# Download from github repo and import .py file from the repo for usage

Tags: python, git

I'm working on a project that needs some utility functions from a open-source git repo. Currently, I download the utilities function locally and import it in my python code like this:

```
path_to_spacenet_utils = 'path/to/my/local/satellite_project/utilities'
sys.path.insert(0,path_to_spacenet_utils)
from spacenetutilities import geoTools as gT
```

However, I want to automate this process:

say, it can download the needed utilities from: https://github.com/SpaceNetChallenge/utilities.git

to a given path and 
import from that path when running the code.

Thank you!

Comment: Literally, the page you link to contains the installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could download a repo from github from python. Here's a couple, and I'm sure there are more:

1: shell out to git, or:
2: download a tgz from github and unpack it

For the first way, do something like this (untested):

```py
import os, subprocess
os.chdir('some dir')
url = `https://github.com/SpaceNetChallenge/utilities.git`
subprocess.call('git clone "{}" spacenetV3'.format(url))
```

For the second way (tgz), use `urllib.request` (also untested):

```py
import urllib.request, subprocess
url = 'https://github.com/SpaceNetChallenge/utilities/archive/spacenetV3.zip'  
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, 'spacenetV3.zip')  
subprocess.call('unzip spacenetV3.zip')
```

In both cases, you'll probably want to check that it's not already downloaded, so it doesn't re-install every time. And of course add lots of error checking.